# c# error after decompiling script "Unexpected symbol `;' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Tags: c#

I'm having C# issues. After decompiling game and turning things into scripts, I keep getting this same error on almost every single script. Here is an example:

```
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer;
using GooglePlayGames.Native;
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
 using UnityEngine;
 [CompilerGeneratedAttribute]
 /*private sealed*/ public class _AcceptFromInbox_c__AnonStorey7
{
// Fields
internal Action <System.Boolean, TurnBasedMatch> callback;
internal NativeTurnBasedMultiplayerClient this; // error is right here. It has something to do with "this".
```

Can someone please help me? I've had this issue for days.

Comment: You can't have a variable named `this`. "This" is the problem with decompilers, don't expect it to create usable code, especially when it comes to anonymous classes like the one you show. In this case `this` is a reference to the encapsulating class.

Comment: Should I just remove the line then? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: You can't just remove the line, especially if `this` is used elsewhere in the class. The real solution is to reconstruct the anonymous type in the context of the class where it is used.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that. Can you show me an example?

Comment: I unfortunately can't, you need to understand how anonymous classes work and the context that they are used in, if I gave you an example it will probably not be applicable to your situation because it depends on how it is used.

Comment: Oh, okay, well thanks for your help anyway!